# How do I calculate the derivative / gradient of covariance?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, gradient, covariance, derivative

Other than numerically calculating, is there a quick way to get the derivative of covariance matrix (of my network activations)?

I'm trying to use it as a penalty term in my cost function in a deep neural network but in order to back-propagate the error through my layers I need to get the derivative.

in Matlab, if 'a' is the activation matrix (neurons*samples) of layer i and 'da' is the derivative of the activation function:

```
covariance = a * a' / (size(a,2)-1);
```

I've tried so far:

```
covarDelta = (da*a' + a*da' ) / (size(a,2)-1);
```

But strangely I've got much closer to the numerically calculated gradient when I derived as if a*a' was in fact a*a=a.^2 (doesn't make sense but it improved things a bit):

```
covarDelta = 2*a/size(a,1);
```

But none of them is correct. Any idea how else to approximate the derivative of covariance?

EDIT: I don't use the covariance matrix itself as a penalty term, I take the mean of all its elements and add that number to the cost function. I use this approach because I tried to come up with a penalty term that would be larger when there's more covariance overall between the signals.

NOTE:I aim to minimize similarity between the signals during the training (I'd also tried penalizing pair-wise mutual information but couldn't find a way to calculate the derivative of that either).

EDIT 2: I've finally used the same derivative provided by the accepted answer but I've changed the cost term to be mean(sqrt(x.^2)). This way both negative and positive covariance will increase the penalty and the derivative is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

Suppose we only have one data point with three dimensions `a = [a1 a2 a3]'`, because the sum of all the elements in the outer product matrix `a*a'` is equivalent to the expansion of `(a1+a2+a3)^2`, the mean of the matrix is `(a1+a2+a3)^2/(3*3)`. So in this case, the derivative for every dimension is of the same value `2*(a1+a2+a3)/(3*3)`.

For more data points that term becomes `((a1+a2+a3)^2+(b1+b2+b3)^2+...)/(3*3)`, and the derivative is `2*(x1+x2+x3)/(3*3)` for data point x (same value for each dimension).

Simply taking the mean might not suit your needs because it will cancel out the positive and negative values in the covariance matrix.

Currently I don't have an environment to verify my answer, please correct me where I'm wrong.

Original Post:

Normally people would use a scalar value as the cost, instead of a (covariance) matrix.

If we denote covariance as a function **cov(x)**, it takes a matrix as input and outputs a matrix.

So the exact derivative is not a single matrix, because its partial derivative with respect to every element of the input matrix is a matrix.

Say the dimension of the input matrix A is m*n, and the dimension of the output matrix C is then m*m. The derivative dA/dC should be a m*m*m*n matrix. See http://mplab.ucsd.edu/tutorials/MatrixRecipes.pdf for details of matrix-by-matrix differentiation.

Comment: You're right @dontloo thanks. I forgot to add that I just base my cost penalty on the covariance matrix but then I use its mean value in the cost function so the actual mapping function is matrix->scalar (see my edit).

Comment: @giber Hi I added some update about the derivatives of the mean, but regarding how to define a sensible loss function is perhaps another question which I don't know much of, cheers.

Comment: Thanks @dontloo I've tried based on your logic: covarDelta = 2*repmat(sum(a,1) / (size(a,1)^2),size(a,1),1); and it worked. But if I simply multiply now this cost penalty with a constant 'betaCovar' to adjust its weight, I'd expect that the derivative will also just be mutliplied by the same constant but this is not the case, the gradient doesn't match once I add a multiplication factor other than 1. Am I wrong? As for the mean cancelling out pos. and neg. covariances, great point, maybe I should take the mean(sqrt(sqr(covar))) instead of mean(covar), what would be the derivative in that case?